# Noob question: Draw a quad parallel to the view

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

ok what I want to do is to draw a quad in the scene that lays on a plane parallel to the view. So it should appear flat.

More in particular, I think I didn't get very well how the mechanism of gluLookAt works in comparison with the functions glTranslate and glRotate:

If I position the view "manually" using the functions glTranslate and glRotate whenever I draw an object its position is relative to the current view. And I understand that this is due to the transformation matrix in the stack.

However, when I use the gluLookAt (that should automatically set the view), the coordinates of the object I want to draw must be "absolute" to be shown properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, if you haven't already read it, I suggest you read the following: http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm That should answer all of your questions (and more ;)

Comment: Yes I read that FAQ but I still don't see the point why for gluLookAt I should use a coordinate system different from the matrix transformation functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/billboarding/) describes how to do billboarding in OpenGL.